# Find in store and run a script when transition link

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I'm just starting to learn ember.js, maybe my question is stupid. I am sorry for them, but I could not find the answer yourself.

- I do want to do the conversions not by id and by symbols links, but
  not work search. I'm writing this: http://jsbin.com/uhohes/1/  (https://gist.github.com/ta-tikoma/6103106)

Comment: in your jsbin there is almost no code whatsoever, can you update it to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: I defined a model Article, wrote to her content. I want to link: "/test2" show up Article test2